# Using multiple layouts in one controller

Tags: php, laravel

I can use `protected $layout = 'layouts.mylayout';` to define which layout Laravel should use when using `$this->layout->content = View::make('myview');` but what should i do if i need to use multiple layouts in the same controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution?
You can override `layout` property in controllers method, assing content to it, etc...
Response is returned automaticaly.

To note, be sure your controller extends `BaseController` which contains `setupLayout` method.
If it does not extend, implement `setupLayout` inside of your controller.

```
<?php

class UsersController extends BaseController
{

    protected $layout = 'users.layout.main';

    public function getList()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('users.list');
    }

    public function getDetail()
    {
        $this->layout = View::make('users.layout.detail');

        $this->layout->content = View::make('users.detail');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you cannot do it using `protected $layout`. But you have many options.

One is to pass the layout name to your view:

```php
class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {

        return View::make('myview', ['layout' => 'layouts.mylayout']);

    }

    public function show()
    {

        return View::make('myview', ['layout' => 'layouts.mySecondLayout']);

    }

    public function create()
    {

            /// this one will use your default layout

        return View::make('myview');

    }

}
```

And `@extends` your layout in your `myview.blade.php`:

```
@extends( isset($layout) ? $layout : Config::get('app.layout')  )

@section('content')
    Here goes your content
@stop
```

And your layout should be something like

```
<html><body>

    THIS IS YOUR LAYOUT 1

    @yield('content')

</body></html>
```

Also, in your app/config/app.php you will have to configure your default layout:

```
return array(

    'layout' => 'layouts.master',

    ...

);
```

Comment: By the time the method is called, $layout has already been transformed into a View object. you would need to do `$this->layout = View::make('layout2');` See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/controllers/BaseController.php#L14 This function gets called just before the method you are routing to does.

Comment: You were so right,  William Cahill-Manley. Just completely changed my answer, thanks.